# Does JPA require the Datasources come from JNDI?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jpa, jndi

I'm using Spring in Tomcat for my webapp. My datasources are built in Spring then published to JNDI using org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate. This is clunky for a few reasons, but my main problem is that it's difficult to control the database being used (which I want to do for testing). Is it possible to use JPA without using JNDI as a lookup service? Ideally, I'd be able to provide the data sources directly to JPA, or through some other method that doesn't rely on a container for the implementation (I have investigated JNDI implementations that aren't provided by a container, but they're not right for my needs).

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: In production, I'm using MySql. In testing I'm using an in-memory only instance of H2 (so it always starts out clean). I'm using Hibernate as my provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a datasource in your spring configuration file.  Here is an excerpt from mine which uses a MySql Database.  To view the full configuration file and project view the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/kmb385/to-thought-tutorial/blob/Post3/src/main/resources/META-INF/application-context.xml).

```
<!-- Database -->
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/to_thought_tutorial" />
    <property name="username" value="tutorial" />
    <property name="password" value="tutorial" />
</bean>

<!-- Entity Manager -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
       <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="tothought-tutorial" />
</bean>
```

I would also encourage you to visit my blog which contains a video describing how to setup a datasource: http://tothought.cloudfoundry.com/post/4

The Spring documentation also includes examples of how to setup a datasource that does not rely upon JNDI: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-datasource

Comment: According to the javadoc for LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean the entity manager is still reads the persistence.xml configuration. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a data source connection directly in your persistence.xml for any given persistence unit:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="BlahBlah" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="xxx"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

If you're not using Hibernate, you can lookup your providers properties, or use the JPA2 standard properties `javax.persistence.jdbc.user`, `javax.persistence.jdbc.password`, `javax.persistence.jdbc.url` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there a way to have dynamic values for those properties? In testing I use different connection parameters than I do in production.